# Why theta(n^2) if m=floor(n/2) for Naive String-matching

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I’m reading CLRS(Introduction to Algorithm, 3rd edition). In the chapter 32.1 about the naive string-matching algorithm, the book says the worst case running time is $\Theta(n^2)$ if $m = \lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$. I get that when $m$ equals $\frac n2$, but I don’t see it when $m$ is less than $\frac n2$. Any hint or suggestion is very appreciated!  m is the length of the pattern string, n is the length of the text to be searched for the pattern. The book uses (n-m+1)m to calculate the running time.

Comment: What do $m$ and $n$ mean here?

Comment: I don't get your question. What's your confusion? What's your understanding if $n$ is odd?

Comment: My understanding is that the running time has to be some quadratic function so it can be theta(n^2). So if m is not n/2, I don’t understand how (n-m+1)m can become a quadratic expression whose highest term is n^2.

Comment: Do you find $(n * ( n / 100 000 000))$  to be $\mathcal \Theta(n^2)$ or not?

Comment: I see but if this is the thought behind, what about n * (2/3n) for the situation that m is not floor but the ceiling of n/2?

Comment: $\frac {2}{3}$  is constant that does not depend on $n$, right? So you have $c * n * n$, which is of order $n^2$. Theta means tight bound. I comment here, because I think the problem comes from Landau notation and may be solved without reference to naive string matching.

Comment: @user917099 Was my answer helpful? Have you considered upvoting and accepting it? Please tell me how it can be improved. (This comment will be deleted upon feedback.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the relevant excerpt from *Introduction to Algorithm* by CLRS, 3rd edition.

> Procedure NAIVE-STRING-MATCHER takes time $O(n - m +1)m$, and this bound is tight in the worst case. For example, consider the text string $a^n$ (a string of $n$ a’s) and the pattern $a^m$. For each of the $n-m+1$ possible values of the shift $s$, the implicit loop on line 4 to compare corresponding characters must execute $m$ times to validate the shift. **The worst-case running time is thus $\Theta((n-m+1)m)$, which is $\Theta(n^2)$ if $m=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.**

Proposition: Let $f(n,m)=\Theta((n-m+1)m)$ be the worst-case running time where $1\le m\le n$. If $m=\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$, then $f(n,m)=\Theta(n^2)$.

Proof. There are constants $c_1, c_2\gt0$ such that for all $1\le m\le n$, 
$$c_1((n-m+1)m)\le f(n,m)\le c_2((n-m+1)m).$$

Now let $m=\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$. Since $1\le n+1-2\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor\le2$, for $n\ge2$, 
$$ \begin{align}
\frac{n^2}4&\lt\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)^2-1\\ 
&\le \left(\frac{n+1}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{n+1-2m}2\right)^2=(n-m+1)m\\
&\le\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)^2-\frac14\lt n^2
\end{align}$$
So $$\frac{c_1}4n^2\lt f(n,m)\lt c_2 n^2,
$$
which says $f(n,m)\in \Theta(n^2)$.